# Notepad++ regexp, find capital letters but ignore certain words

Tags: regex, notepad++, uppercase

I would like to find all capital letters, but I need to ignore certain words/letters

For example: 

`I'm Surprised.
I, Myself I Am Excited.`

In this case here, I'm trying to mark all capitals but exclude the 2 lone `I` and `I'm`.

This is my starting point:
`[A-Z]?(I)`, but it only finds words containing `I`.

EDIT:
Another thing came up. I will also need to exclude the first capital letter after a period `.`, question mark `?` or exclamation mark `!`, but not if it is 3 dots `...`
And if the word after those is starting with a lowercase, it will have to be marked as well.
Also, there could be other junk in between (like numbers or other punctuation such as `:` or `,`).

Example:

`- I'm surprised.
- Myself I am excited.
846 3:34,343535
Said "Where..."
No... 
846 3:34,343535
Not... not interested. - PUT. what is it?
"It's gone"
846 3:34,343535
Tonight.`

In this case,  I need to mark the capitals of `Where`, `No`, `Not`, `PUT` and `Tonight`. As well as the lowercase `not` and `what` (since those are coming after a . ! or ?).
Again, there could be some other junk in between the period and the next word like `"` or `'`

Expected output: [image](http://image.prntscr.com/image/7b6802b53437497eaf4da1bb37f1b850.png)

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
(?!\bI\b)[A-Z]
```

**Make sure *`Match case`* is enabled!** Else, use `(?-i)(?!\bI\b)[A-Z]`.

The negative lookahead will fail all cases of `I` where it is a whole word.

Also, pay special attention to the *Match case* option - it should be ON.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But another thing came up. I need to exclude the first capital letter after a `.`,`?`,or`!` But if that letter is lowercase, it needs to be marked as well. I have updated the question to give an example for this.

Comment: doesn't work. Your regex finds also words such as "îmbogatit" that doesnt have capital letters

Comment: @JustMe The `îmbogatit` word is not found with my regex. Are you sure you checked the `Match case` option? Or, use `(?-i)(?!\bI\b)[A-Z]` then. Note the regex here is not meant to find "words", only the uppercase letters other than `I` word. Most probably, you have another problem, not the one in OP.

Comment: thanks. Yes, this new regex works.  Please update your answer, and add also this new regex. as an alternative method.

Comment: @JustMe But the one in the answer DOES work, see the `Match case` option ON as shown in the screenshot. I added the regex from above comment to the answer.

Comment: oh, yes, indeed. Must check the "Match Case". But, also, the regex you done today, is a better option. Add is to the answer, please, as an alternative method.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite confused about your requirement. It's not clear and the output image throwing 404 error.

I am trying to resolve your problem please verify:

```
txt = `- I'm surprised.
- Myself I am excited.
846 3:34,343535
Said "Where..."
No... 
846 3:34,343535
Not... not interested. - PUT. what is it?
"It's gone"
846 3:34,343535
Tonight.`
```

*Solution-01: (with case validation)*

```
regex: /[A-Z]+\w*[\.\!\?]+/g
txt.match(/[A-Z]+\w*[\.\!\?]+/g)
['Where...', 'No...', 'Not...', 'PUT.', 'Tonight.']
```

[image]

*Solution-02: (without case validation)*

```
regex: /[A-Z]+\w*[\.\!\?]+/gi
txt.match(/[A-Z]+\w*[\.\!\?]+/gi)
['surprised.', 'excited.', 'Where...', 'No...', 'Not...', 'interested.', 'PUT.', 'it?', 'Tonight.']
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

@Toto just gave me an alternative answer ( If I want to find only the words that starts with a capital letter):

Use the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\b[A-Z]\w+`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

---

Comment: The current question is not about matching *words*, but the *capital letters* not in a specific word. `. matches newline` option has nothing to do with the `\b[A-Z]\w+` pattern since it only modifies the behavior of the `.` pattern.